# Django squashed migrations: NodeNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, database-migration

Running Django 1.8.9.

I just squashed migrations for 3 apps and deployed. When `./manage.py migrate` was run, I got this:

```
django.db.migrations.graph.NodeNotFoundError: Migration app2.0001_squashed_0019 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node (u'app1', u'0001_squashed_0028')
```

`app1.0001_squashed_0028` was present on disk though, as were the migrations being replaced. The Django migration system should have had all the information it needed to migrate forwards.

I was able to work around the issue by:

1. renaming the 2 new squashed migrations that depended on `app1.0001_squashed_0028` to `*.bak`,
2. running migrations,
3. then renaming the `*.bak` files back,
4. and rerunning migrations.

Migrations worked fine locally and in staging, so I'm guessing the reason this happened is because production wasn't yet up to date with the pre-squashed migrations.

I found several squashing related issue tickets, but I'm not sure any of them are for this same bug. Anyone know if this is a known issue? Was I doing something wrong/is there a better way to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

You expressed confusion about the error message, because:

> app1.0001_squashed_0028 was present on disk though, as were the migrations being replaced. The Django migration system should have had all the information it needed to migrate forwards.

Whether you see a file on the disk isn't definitive, though. To find out what migrations Django knows about for the project, use the [management command `showmigrations`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#showmigrations).

If the migration you expect to be there isn't even listed, then that's the answer to why Django is claiming that migration is not found.